# Find all webpages without internal links

Tags: 9

In MediaWiki there is a nice feature allowing the user to list all webpages without internal links in that MediaWiki website.

Is there a way to get such data in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  Drupal is not a wiki and it doesn't function like one.

In Drupal, a simple "page" may include:

- a node of a content type ("Page" or "Article"
- one or more menus (header and footer, for example)
- one or more blocks (footer, sidebar, information block, etc.)

All of these may have internal links.

More complex Drupal pages can be made with the Views module and include multiple nodes or other entities.

As a result, there is no function for isolating individual "pages" of a Drupal website, and it would be very hard to implement one.